# Lebesgue measure of sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Calculate the Lebesgue measure of following sets:

1. $A=\{(x,y): x\in\mathbb{Q} \vee y\in\mathbb{Q}\}$
2. $B=\{(x,y): x-y\in\mathbb{Q}\}$

So I guess I need to calculate an integral over those sets. But I have no idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Both A and B are countable union of lines.

Comment: Could I do: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_A(x,y) d\lambda(x,y)$?
And $\chi_A(x,y)=1$ when $x \in \mathbb{Q} \vee y \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\chi_A(x,y)=0$ when $x,y$ aren't in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Using Radon's hint would be better.

Comment: So in 1. I've got countable union of lines in $\mathbb{R^2}$. So the measure will be 0?